# How to initialize a tuple in Python using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

I'm working on course work for school, the problem is as follows,

> The elements of tuple can be initialized so that tup[i] == i in a recursive fashion as follows:
>
> - A tuple of size 0 is already initialized
> - Otherwise:
>
>   - set the last element of the tuple to n-1 (where n is the number of elements in the tuple)
>   - initialize the portion of the tuple consisting of the first n-1 elements
>
> Write a function named init that takes one argument, a tuple of the proper length, and returns an tuple initialized as described above.

```
def init(tupin):
    if len(tupin) == 0:
        return tupin
    else:
        return (0,) + init(tupin[1:])
```

so far this is all I have been able to get.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the output its looking for is [0,1,2] its outputting [0,0,0]

Comment: Since you never add anything but `(0,)`, that's not surprising.

Comment: Please show how you intend to call your function.

Comment: It calls the function with a random tuple of any length.
for example it may use [8,8,8,8] and expects [0,1,2,3]
I'm not sure how to get above 0 without a loop. And it doesn't want a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You skipped the step *set the last element of the tuple to `n-1`*. You can do that by appending `(len(tupin)-1,)`.

```
def init(tupin):
    if len(tupin) == 0:
        return tupin
    else:
        return init(tupin[1:]) + (len(tupin)-1, )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```py
def init(tupin):
    if not isinstance(tupin, tuple):
        raise TypeError("Please, supply a tuple to the function")
    if len(tupin):
        return init(tupin[:-1]) + (len(tupin)-1,)
    else:
        return tupin
```